# LaunchD Rclone Mount Script Not Loading

Tags: macos, launchd, rclone

Could anyone help me with this script to mount a drive using rclone. Not sure why but it doesn't mount my drive when started.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.zerowidth.launched.rclone-mount-gdrive</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/rclone cmount --allow-other --dir-cache-time 72h --drive-chunk-size 64M --log-level INFO --vfs-read-chunk-size 32M --vfs-read-chunk-size-limit off gdrive: /Users/Lee/GDrive --vfs-cache-mode writes</string>
    </array>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/Lee/Documents/Logs/rclone-media.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/Lee/Documents/Logs/stdout</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```